# AutoFixture adhering to FluentValidation

Tags: fluentvalidation, autofixture

I'm currently learning using AutoFixture and can't figure out if there is a neat way to let AutoFixture generate a specimen that adheres the rules defined in my validator using FluentValidation.

### Desired Solution

Let AutoFixture generate speciman following rules defined in validator.

### Current Situation

AutoFixture generates random properties that violate the validation rules.

### Question

Can AutoFixture create specimens adhering a AbstractValidator from FluentValidation?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box AutoFixture supports only DataAnnotations attributes as a means to generate models that would pass validation.

To my knowledge there is currently no glue library that would integrate AutoFixture with FluentValidation.

As a solution you might want to create customizations for your models that would adhere to the rules defined in your validators. Then compose the customizations in a way that would make sense for the tested scenario.